Are CATE/ITE estimates supposed to be normally distributed?
I am doing uplift modeling and predicting ITEs for a bunch of individuals. When I plot these, should I expected them to be normally distributed. One of the models I tried had the predictions be bi- or even tri-modal, and I wasn't sure if that was not supposed to happen.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you conditioning on X to keep it constant within each histogram, or are you mixing everything together?
